# What happens when you get silkscreen over a via?

Tags: pcb

See image below;

[image]

My suspicions would say that part of the silkscreen would disappear over a via, does this happen in production?

Comment: There's no reason the silkscreen would magically "disappear" over a via unless your EDA package crops it off.  Naively, the fab may just do exactly what your gerbers say, expecting you know the consequences.

Comment: I've never worked with a fab that doesn't just chop off any silk screen over solder mask.  Its really not a good thing to get slik screen ink on your solder points, really screws with solder performance (at least in reflow, hand assembly it doesn't matter as much).

Comment: your image does not show the characteristic red solder mask overlay found in Geda PCB? (I assume this is the software your using) if you did apply the solder mask layer - by default it would cover all your vias with solder mask, unless you stated otherwise - see my answer below for more details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default gEDA PCB Designer will just cover all the vias with the solder mask, to change this you can hover over the via with your cursor and press <*key*> k to uncover the vias, use <*key*> *shift* k to go back to tented.

Check out PCB's manual entry on vias for more info-

http://pcb.gpleda.org/pcb-cvs/pcb.html#Via-Objects

Plus- [This page](http://www.delorie.com/pcb/docs/gs/gs.html) by DJ Delorie describes how Geda PCB handles solder masking, it also has some great illustrations of the different masked vias.

Comment: That's cool, I've just been doing some basic tutorial videos on Geda, it's a fantastic design package, but it can be quite daunting chewing through the manual

Comment: Agreed, it's a very powerful package but takes considerable learning to work with - but it's one of the few programs to design open hardware on with open formats.

Comment: I press the k key and the via appears to bulge, if I keep pressing it the polygon gets distorted and PCB crashes eventually, how much is too much?

Comment: Just press it once and it should clear the metal ring of the via, press it a few times to get more clearance if desired, use *shift k* to make it smaller again.

Comment: i think you mean it covers all the vias with solder mask, not silk screen

Comment: cheers mark! - I didn't spot that

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what's already been done with the via.  Vias can be:

- Filled - A silver-based epoxy inserted so that the via can be...
- Capped - Copper layers cover the filler.  The via can now be used as a pad.
- Plugged - A blob of soldermask is applied to the via. Creates a slight bump.
- Tented - Just plain soldermask film covers the via, often slightly concave.  Limited to small-diameter vias.
- Plain.  Nothing is done, this is your ordinary via.

If a via (or other metal surface) has not had any of these treatments, the silkscreen will not stick to the via.  No big deal.

I recommend plugging all vias in non-development boards to maintain insulation for the trace.   Then, silkscreen might be distorted, but it will be visible.

In the end, the answer is "Ask your fab house."

Of course, the better option is to re-arrange of your silk. Keep all silk  aligned in the same direction, for the sake of your neck.  Be consistent locally with respect to what side of the component the silk is located on.  If an area is a little bit too tight, move the silk away and draw a line (in silk) pointing to the component.  If everything is too tight, or you want a less busy looking board, leave off components that are never going to change or be looked at (decoupling caps, pullup/pulldown resistors, protection diodes) in favor of clarity for components which are going to be looked at (CONNECTORS, integrated circuits, power components).

The image you've provided is nearly indecipherable to me.  Either of the large components could be U6, and the two-pad device at the bottom could be R22, 27, or 18. Also, if that is an 0603, then it looks like that text will be painfully small.  **All silk should have a width of at least 6 mils** for most fab houses (and easier reading).  In Eagle, this means that size x ratio > 0.006.  0.08" text at a 10% ratio will produce 8 mils, which is workable, and 0.05" text at a 12% ratio just makes it.  Bigger/bolder fonts for important stuff are nice.  Also, **use vector fonts, not proportional fonts.**  This is based on my experience with Eagle, but the font you use isn't encoded in the Gerbers, unless you use a vector font.  Otherwise, your fab may substitute some other font, which will cause all your careful alignment to be screwed up.  It appears that you're doing the latter, but not the former.

Comment: I've sometimes thought it would be nice to have an option to have a printed (paper) version of a layout with designators placed directly on top of component footprints, rather than to the side.  Do any layout packages make it easy to have legends placed near (but not over) components when making a board, but directly on the footprint when making a paper reference print?

Comment: @supercat - Every layout package I have used has layers.  It would be easy to make a 'real silkscreen' and a 'print-only pseudo-silkscreen' layer.  Then, in your CAM/output generator, create a PCB output job and a paper output job, and enable just the associated layer.  You'd have to add the designators to all your packages, which could be tedious the first time.

Answer (score 6):

Just as an example this is a silkscreen gone wrong, it's all over the pads. Luckily I just made 2 boards. (9 mil for spaces, 16 mils for traces).
[image: Silkscreen gone wrong]

Comment: What were the results of doing this... did it work? or did you have to redo them?

Comment: As of now I just removed the silkscreen over the SMD pads with a knife (yeah, a TQFP64 plus 4 0805 and 4 0603, a mess of a jewellery work), I am about to fire it up, but the reflow was just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the fab house. I have found at the fab houses that I use they don't even attempt to put silkscreen over a via. It is possible though that when they put the solder mask down it covers the entire hole allowing for the silkscreen to attach to something.